# Why is this recursive routine giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)?

Tags: c++, xcode, pointers, recursion

```
void BinTree::arrayToBSTreeHelper(NodeData* toRead[], Node* current, int low, int high) // ******
{
    if (low >= high)
    {
        return;
    }

    int midPoint = (low + high) / 2;

    cout << "low, midPoint, and high at entry to helper: " << low << "  " << midPoint << "  " << high << endl; // ****** prints 0, 6 and 13

    insert(toRead[midPoint]); // ****** insert takes a NodeData*
    arrayToBSTreeHelper(toRead, current->left, low, midPoint); // ERROR
    arrayToBSTreeHelper(toRead, current->right, midPoint + 1, high);
}
```

The printout of low, midPoint, and high happens once, then the "bad access" message is given on the first recursive call. "insert" has been tested and seems to work correctly.

There seems to be something wrong with passing the array "toRead" of NodeData* recursively but I can't figure out what it is.

Environment is Xcode 7.1.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There seems to be something wrong with passing the array "toRead" of
>   NodeData* recursively

That is not correct.

It failed when (and because) `current` was zero.

If you believed something about your design made `current` reliably not zero at that point, you need to fix that design error.  Because we can see it **IS** zero.

If other parts of the design were not supposed to guarantee `current` points to a valid object at this point, then the code you showed should be testing it before using it.